# Combining Associations in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model in Ruby on rails that has a self referencing association

```
  # Friendships
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :class_name => "User", :through => :friendships, :uniq => true do 
    def bySource(sourceId)
        where("friendships.source_id = ?", sourceId)
    end
  end
```

Each user has an associated friendStatusDescriptor that tells information about the friendship.  Currently I have this association tied to the user model

```
  has_many :friendStatuses, :class_name => "FriendStatusDescriptor", :source => :user, :uniq => true
```

I would like this to come back in the friends array instead.  So when I do something like

```
 render :json => user.friends, :include => :status
```

each friend listed would have a field called status with this FriendStatusDescriptor object.  How do I properly connect those things to make this work?  I'm guessing I could have a method in the friends association, but I'm not sure how that would look as far as getting called on each individual friend during render.

Comment: Since `status` describes the association between users, not the users themselves, it should probably be a field of the `Friendship` model, or a model associated with it, rather than attached to the User model.

Comment: You are exactly right sir.  Then my render looks like this and I'm good to go `render :json => user.friendships, :only => [], :include => [{:friend => {:except => [:password] } }, :status]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `status` describes the association *between* Users, not the Users themselves, it should be a field of the `Friendship` model, or a model associated with it, rather than attached to the `User` model.